# how to create reference to a value of a subhash member in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would like to use reference to make the code shorter
I make it simple, only one level of depth here :

```
my %cx = ( 'a' => ( "A" => 7, "B" => 8), 'b' => ( "Z" => 20 ));
# I want a ref to the B's value for testing, with a possible increment action :
my $ref = \$cx{a}{B}; # so I just put a \ before
if ($$ref and $$ref < 10) { $$ref ++; } # will give $cx{a}{B} = 9
# I have the same need for inner references, for example :
my $ref = \$stock{$stockName}->{places}->{$otherHashRef->{andItsKey}}
```

But this doesn't work

Comment: (Gotta put a line feed after the triple backtick. What's after the tripple backtick is taken as the language for highlighting purposes.)

Comment: Same error using \$cx{a}{B} or \\($cx{a}{B}) :    
Can't use string ("A") as a HASH ref while "strict refs" in use  ..

Comment: That's not what you said in your question ("will give `$cx{a}{B} = 9`")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parens don't contruct anything; they just change precedence. So,

```
my %cx = ( 'a' => ( "A" => 7, "B" => 8), 'b' => ( "Z" => 20 ));
```

is just a weird way of writing

```
my %cx = ( 'a' => "A", 7 => "B", 8 => 'b', "Z" => 20 );
```

Curlies create a hash and returns a reference to a hash, so you want

```
my %cx = ( 'a' => { "A" => 7, "B" => 8 }, 'b' => { "Z" => 20 });
```

For example,

```
$ perl -MData::Dumper -e'
   {
      my %cx = ( 'a' => { "A" => 7, "B" => 8 }, 'b' => { "Z" => 20 });
      my $ref = \$cx{a}{B};
      ++$$ref;
      print(Dumper(\%cx));
   }

   {
      my %stock;
      my $stockName = "abc";
      my $otherHashRef = { andItsKey => 'def' };
      my $ref = \$stock{$stockName}->{places}->{$otherHashRef->{andItsKey}};
      ++$$ref;
      print(Dumper(\%stock));
   }
'
$VAR1 = {
          'a' => {
                   'A' => 7,
                   'B' => 9
                 },
          'b' => {
                   'Z' => 20
                 }
        };
$VAR1 = {
          'abc' => {
                  'places' => {
                                'def' => 1
                              }
                }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks... yes, I need to be carefull with "()" and "{}"